# How to make a variable to be accessible on any page?

Tags: php

I've made a login script (http://pastebin.com/bCpXYwPq), and I know it's prone to SQL injection, I'm fixing that later.

Anyway, I need the variable '$users', so I can echo it anywhere.

Example: On the account page, I want it to echo the email address.
How would I do that if the variable is only stored in the login script?

Comment: Hi there. I think you have about four different user accounts here - would appreciate it if you would stick to just one. It'll benefit you by allowing you to accrue reputation points. Please also post code in your question, not on a separate pasteboard.

Comment: I just want to point out that if you ask such a question, your "login script" will probably not work as intended and leave you with some serious security issues.

Answer (score 2):

Put the serialized variable `$users` on `$_SESSION`

like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['users'] = serialize($users);
```

And to catch the $user again:

```
session_start();
$users = unserialize($_SESSION['users']);
```

Comment: session_start();
$_SESSION['users'] = $users;

Comment: and to serialize use:
    http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php

Comment: This wouldn't work. I need to store the whole row of data, not just the email and username.

Comment: Yes, so put the entire '$users' variable into SESSION. You can parse to JSON or Serialize.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dig into sessions (http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

login.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["username"]=$username;
$_SESSION["email"]=$email;
$specialdata=array("a","b","c");
$_SESSION["specialdata"]=serialize($specialdata);
```

On all other pages you need access to that data:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
// User not logged in
echo "You aren't logged in"
}
else
{
// Logged in
echo "The username is: " . $_SESSION["username"];
echo "Your email is: " . $_SESSION["email"];
$specialdata=unserialize($_SESSION["specialdata"]);
echo "First element of special data: " . $specialdata[0]; // Prints a
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. I need to store the whole row of data, not just the email and username.

Comment: Well, you can do $_SESSION["data"]=serialize($your_data); and afterwards unserialize($_SESSION["data"]);

Comment: So, $_SESSION["users"]=json_encode($users); on the success login script. And json_decode($_SESSION["users"]); on the other pages?

Comment: @ThomasDoyle What row?

Comment: I extended my example to cover special datatypes, this can hold any type of data, including classes.

Answer (score 0):

**Sessions**. definetly. Use `session_start();` on all pages so the sessions are activated on the login page just declare the `$_SESSION['username'];` and you can use `$_SESSION['username'];` everywhere.